# Azure Logic Apps trigger does not give tracking id

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am working on a logic app in azure. I have created a custom api app that receives Tracking id as input and does . Now i have 5 actions and 1 trigger in my logic app.

I am using Http Listener as my logic app trigger. Now i want to get the tracking id of a particular run and pass that same tracking id into my custom api app as input in the same run.

I Followed the below link and tried to get the tracking Id from the trigger
[Link to resource](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/logicapps/archive/2015/09/23/adding-insights-and-telemetry-to-logic-apps-through-power-bi.aspx)

I tried the following things in my logic app to get tracking id:
1) `@triggers().trackingId` - didnt work
2)`@trigger().trackingId` - didnt work
3)`@trigger().trackingid` - didnt work
4)`@triggers().trackingid` - didnt work
5)`@actions('triggername')` - in this case my logic trigger stops working i.e. i cannot trigger my logic app anymore
6)`@triggers()` - in this case i get the whole trigger object but do not get tracking id anywhere in the object.

what should i do to achieve what i want in this case ?

Comment: Have you tried `@triggers().outputs.trackingId` or `@triggers().outputs.body.trackingId`?

Comment: Tried it, but its not working, its my other actions in the same logic app are giving out tracking id, but the http listener trigger is not giving out tracking id. When i do @actions('actionname').triggerId, then i get a trigger id in all other cases except trigger, but when i put trigger's name in place of action name, my logic app stop working(its not triggered at all)

Answer (score 2):

If you are just looking for unique ID for a workflow, which should accessible in an action in your logic app, use `@workflow()['run']['name']`. This will return the unique runId that is generated for each run.